# Can't remotely connect with hostname, but it works with IP

Tags: windows, networking, macos, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am tying to connect to Windows 10 machine from a macOS Sierra using Microsoft Remote Desktop. The Windows machine is behind a switch. Both machines run on a local network.

I can connect to it using IP, but I can't using hostname. I've got the hostname from `192.168.1.1` router DHCP table.

Error when trying to connect with hostname:

> We couldn't connect to the remote PC because the PC can't be found. Please provide the fully-qualified name or the IP address of the remote PC, and then try again. Error code: 0x104.

What could be the reason and what should I do?

Comment: are you sure the hostname resolves on the Mac? Perhaps it isn't set to use your router for dns.

Comment: Under Prefernces->Network->Advanced->DNS I have DNS server address 192.168.1.1. Shouldn't that do it?

Comment: probably not. Your router probably understand internet DNS but not on your LAN. Mac and Windows use different protocols

Answer (score 3):

I recently just encountered and solved this exact error with Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.3.12 (1801) on both macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) and macOS Catalina (10.15.5). I was able to connect without issue if the IP address of the Windows machine was used, but would get Error Code: 0x104 if the hostname was attempted.

The solution that worked was appending ".local" to the end of the host name.

One thing to note is the iOS/iPadOS version of the app worked without any problems, and did not require anything added to the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Delete any custom DNS server(s) under ***System Preferences » Network » Advanced » DNS*** and use the local network's DNS to get it to resolve via hostname.

Comment: This was my exact problem. You prevented (additional) hours of heads banging against walls. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem: I was able to connect from macOS via IP address but not via FQDN (like `rdp-host.example.com`). Adding `.local` to the end of the hostname did not work nor did pruning DNS servers from system preferences.

What did work was adding a dot to the end of the hostname: `rdp-host.example.com.`

cf. http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html

Comment: that's really strange, this worked on a domain connected pc, while all other devices in my network can connect without dot

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is flush the DNS:

1. Open CMD and type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press enter.
2. Wait to when it has been done!
3. Write down `ipconfig /registerdns` and press enter.

Wait 10-15 minutes and try again to connect not using the IP.